# Proof of unique solution to a minimization over two sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given two non-strictly ascending sequences, prove that no rearrangement of terms in either sequences will produce a smaller $S$.

$A=1,2,3,4,5...\\B=2,3,4,5,6...$

$S=\left|A_1 - B_1\right|+\ldots +\left|A_n - B_n\right|$

Assume the sequences are the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any two sequences of length $n$, say $\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle$ and $\langle b_1,\ldots,b_n\rangle$. Without loss of generality assume that $a_1\le a_2\le\ldots\le a_n$. Now show that if there are indices $j$ and $k$ such that $1\le j<k\le n$ and $b_j>b_k$, then interchanging $B_j$ and $B_k$ never increases $S$ (and can decrease it). Since you can always put the second sequence into non-decreasing order by a sequence of interchanges of this type, it follows that $S$ is minimal when the second sequence is also non-decreasing.

If worse comes to worst, consider all possible arrangements of $a_j,a_k,b_j$, and $b_k$ individually; some of them are

$$\begin{align*}
&a_j\le a_k\le b_k<b_j\;,\\
&a_j\le b_k\le a_k<b_j\;,\text{ and}\\
&a_j\le b_k<b_j\le a_k\;.
\end{align*}$$

In each case you want to compare $$|a_j-b_j|+|a_k-b_k|$$ with $$|a_j-b_k|+|a_k-b_j|\;.$$

Comment: @brianmscott Just to make sure, did you mix up "increase" and "decrease" in your third sentence?

Comment: @GreenShape: No, it's what I wanted: remember, in that argument we're starting with the second sequence *not* in non-decreasing order, so we want to show that reversing a decreasing pair improves $S$ (makes it smaller), or at worst leaves it unchanged.